# Parse progress with sed (or something else)

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

I am trying to parse progress from one program (it is mkvmerge, but I hope that does not matter):

```
 echo -en "Progres: 0%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b25%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b\b50%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b\b75%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -e "\b\b\b100%"
```

I would like to get the number without "Progress " and "%". This works:

```
echo -e "Progress: 0%"| sed -e 's/Progress: //' -e 's/%//' -e 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

But when the Progress keeps changing, it does not work. Is there a way to do it (even without sed and with something else)?

Comment: Yeah, I thought this would be pretty hard, but Eduardo had an answer in no time:-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\b` characters are changing the current line so a new line never gets printed. You're not going to have a great deal of success out of the box using a line-based stream editor like sed on that kind of input.

If `mkvmerge` is generating this kind of output first try looking for a switch that makes it use some other kind of progress indicator (preferrably one that prints newlines).

If that doesn't work you can try replacing the backspaces with newlines:

```
( echo -en "Progres: 0%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b25%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b\b50%" ; sleep 1 ; 
  echo -en "\b\b\b75%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -e "\b\b\b100%" ) | tr '\b' '\n'
```

Add some unbuffering using `stdbuf` and it seems we're there, at least for your example:

```
( echo -en "0%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b25%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -en "\b\b\b50%" ; sleep 1 ; 
  echo -en "\b\b\b75%" ; sleep 1 ; echo -e "\b\b\b100%" ) | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\b' '\n' | 
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 sed -e 's/Progress: //' -e 's/%//' -e 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

The output, which appeared in the screen as it was generated thanks to `stdbuf` (I trimmed some spurious newlines):

```
0
25
50
75
100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never figure this out on my own:-). In the end, it results in this beasts:
`mkvmerge -o  "out.mkv" --language 0:eng --forced-track 0:no --language 1:eng --forced-track 1:no -a 1 -d 0 -S -T --no-global-tags --no-chapters "path_to_movie.avi" --track-order 0:0,0:1 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\r' '\n' |   stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 grep 'Progress:' | stdbuf -i0 -e0  -o0 sed -e 's/Progress: //' -e 's/%//' -e 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/' | zenity --width=480 --progress --auto-close --percentage=0 --text="Bla" --title="Merging subtitles with video, please wait..."`

Answer (score 3):

Try piping through `tr` to turn carriage returns (most likely what it's using) into line feeds:

```
<cmd> | tr '\r' '\n' | sed ...
```

Then you can work with it separated into lines like you normally would.